# Does AXI Read Interleaving only valid for AXI interconnect?

Tags: interconnect, axi4

Understand that master can issue multiple read commands & expect the readback data might happen in interleaved manner.

Something to clarify here which is for single master to single slave scenario, it seems like not possible for the read interleave happen as the slave only can only process single read at a time. This means the 2nd read request will be only carried out after the 1st request is completed. Is this assumption correct?

To extend the read interleave question & assuming this use case only valid in AXI interconnect. In this case, the arbiter seems like compulsory for all the readback data coming from different slave & the arbiter to determine which readback data that has higher priority can or through round-robin way to return to the master.

is the above interpretation correct?

Comment: AXI specs doesn't talk about arbitration scheme or how interconnect should be or whether read should be completed out-of-order in multi master multi slave, or in-order in case of single master single slave etc ...These are all implementation specific. AXI specs in fact talks only about point to point communication, ie., just a single interface between Master and Slave.

Comment: **If** the particular slave in question can only process one read at a time, then your assumption is probably correct. But there's nothing to prevent a generic slave from buffering requests internally and handling them out of order, such as processing all pending requests for the current page or bank before switching to a different page/bank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a device can only handle one operation at a time, sure.  But this is not a valid assumption.  It is common for things like DRAM controllers to handle several concurrent operations to hide latency, reordering things internally to improve performance.